# Command not found Error when trying to extract number from specific string NumberLong("43494254014573") using bash

Tags: bash

I need to extarct the number from the string when I try to I get error

```
val2="NumberLong(\"43494254014573\")"

$val2|awk -F'"' '{print $2}'
```

> -bash: NumberLong("43494254014573"): command not found

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to `echo` the variable, or somehow put it into the stdin pipe of the `awk` command. e.g.

```
val2="NumberLong(\"43494254014573\")"
echo $val2|awk -F'"' '{print $2}'
```

OR

```
val2="NumberLong(\"43494254014573\")"
awk -F'"' '{print $2}' <<< "$val2"
```

Your current solution attempts to execute the value of `$val2`, which clearly doesn't exist as an executable.

Edit:

You can assign the result to a variable using command substitution (https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Command-Substitution.html):

```
val2="NumberLong(\"43494254014573\")"
num=$(awk -F'"' '{print $2}' <<< "$val2")
echo $num
```

Comment: How do i assign it to a variable like $val3=$val2|awk -F'"' '{print $2}'